# How to extract, or otherwise create seamlessly looping music from Majora's Mask?

Tags: nintendo-64, zelda-majoras-mask

I really enjoy *The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask* for the Nintendo 64, I bought a copy when it was new. I love it.

I watch various live streams daily of people playing this game in the background (as my own kind of ASMR). Unfortunately, they often talk and do various annoying things in the game, or there are audio glitches because they don't use real hardware, etc.

I do have a copy of the official OST of the game on my computer. Unfortunately, each song is reduced to one "lap", so to speak, and then fades out. It does not loop naturally like it does when you actually play the game, so I cannot recreate the ambience from my favourite locations in the game.

If I were to sit here with Audacity and try to splice them together so they loop seamlessly, I will be spending eternity. I have tried that in the past for other things, and it just never works out for me. I keep hearing the annoying little gap or that one single spot which doesn't sound quite right.

On a real Nintendo 64, the background music perfectly loops in spite of beginning differently (or so it seems to my ears).

What (if anything) can I do to extract or otherwise get seamlessly looping Majora's Mask tracks, rather than these short and "fading" ones?

Comment: This seems to be more about editing music/sound files than it is playing video games. That is probably the reason why someone down voted.

Comment: Chances are, you aren't the first person to have this exact problem. People on YouTube create long loops of game music all the time, If you search on Youtube for `<track name> loop` or `track name 1 hour` (or `10 hours` etc) you'll usually find them pretty quickl;y, for example: [Clock Town Day 1 10 Hours](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_UxDoPO6Yo)

Comment: You'll find quite a few looping versions are online already - try searching youtube for Clock Town Day 1 10 Hours, for instance, and you'll get https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOiC0R9O3sk

Comment: Every game doesn't have loop version of their music in their files, since it takes unnecessary spaces. Developer can loop their songs by writing few line of codes (or might even just a line of codes).

Answer (score 0):

Audacity (if that is the audio editing software you elect to use) has a looping function, here is a tutorial video on how to use those:

Also here is a [Youtube playlist](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRMQdaBibjYeX24PW11L61S4ZOKpbsuLm) of each track extended to 20 or so minutes.

Additionally, if you are wondering why the audio loops perfectly on actual hardware, that is because most game music is looped (or assembled) using scripts during the game, and typically those scripts allow for ignoring intro parts of songs etc, to dynamically handle the music. A good example of dynamically assembled music on physical hardware (though emulation is not far behind) is dancing mad from final fantasy 6. The 17 minute song is dynamically assembled based on what phase of the fight the player is on. Hopefully this answered your editing question as well as inquiries about how games loop audio.